# Fiddler changes zipped request causing a failure

Tags: fiddler

I have an app that sends zipped HTTP POST. With Fiddler running, requests are failing because the server is unable to unzip the body. Shutting down Fiddler eliminates the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I've never had a problem with this. In Fiddler, click `Help`>`Send Feedback`. Send a SAZ File containing your traffic and I'll be happy to fix this if there's a problem in Fiddler here.

Comment: One caveat: You haven't ticked the `Decode` button on Fiddler's toolbar, have you? If so, Fiddler will decompress the request body and update the headers. A properly functioning server will not have a problem with that, but if the server is buggy, all bets are off.

Comment: Decode button is not clicked, i.e. decoding is disabled.

Comment: Sent you the SAZ file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the capture provided, the request body is compressed twice (`gzip`, then `gzip` again) but the `Content-Encoding` header incorrectly lists only `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

The request's `Content-Length` header is also incorrect: It is `Content-Length: 141` but the body sent to the server is actually `164` bytes in length. The original body was `159` bytes in length, the first compression pass shrinks it to `141` bytes in length, and when the already-compressed content is recompressed it grows to `164` bytes in length.

By default, Fiddler doesn't care about double-compressed content or invalid Content-Encoding headers, as it doesn't attempt to decompress the request body unless you tell it to do so. The only explanation I can think of is that perhaps you have written some rule in FiddlerScript which is blindly compressing the request body and it's leading to this problem. One other reason to suspect this is that Fiddler would have complained about an invalid `Content-Length` header when reading this request, and the fact that it didn't suggests that the request body was modified inside Fiddler itself.

Comment: Turns out that there was a script that would automatically compress/zip the body if `Content-Encoding:gzip` header was present. And Fiddler as expected did that for every request, not only for those that were handcrafted in the composer.

Comment: FWIW, you can check `oSession.oFlags.ContainsKey("X-FROM-BUILDER")` to see if the request came from the Composer.